# Checking for a click for object that will be created later

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, if i have jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
        //Add stuff to table
        $('#items_table tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="button" id="btn2" value="second button" /></td>/tr>');
    });
    //Created button above is triggered
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        alert('btn 2 was clicked');
    });
});
```

Nothing will happen when i click on the "btn2". I guess that's becaouse it's not there when $(document).ready() ? If i send that js for btn2 into the table row, it works fine. something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    //Add stuff to table
    $('#items_table tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="button" id="btn2" value="second button" /><script type="text/javascript ..... BLAH $(\'#btn\').click BLAH </script>;
    });
});
```

Ideas?

Comment: you need to wrap it inside a `$(function({..btn2 code}` which is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 5):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to let the table delegate the event to elements that may appear later :

```
$('#items_table').on('click', '#btn2', function(){
    alert('btn 2 was clicked');
});
```

Comment: To clarify, you could use 'on' regardless, but key to this solution is the fact that on's second argument is a selector that runs when the event is fired, as opposed to the OP's original code which was a selector that ran once at the document.ready and found 0 elements (so never bound a click handler).

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to a parent element using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and pass the selector as an argument. This works for dynamically added elements as well...

```
 $('#items_table').on('click', '#btn2', function(){
    alert('btn 2 was clicked');
 });
```

Comment: This answer is exactly what dystroy posted three minutes before you.